# hiding keyboard issue

Tags: android

I am using the following code to hide the keyboard when a button is clicked:

```
private OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.myProfileDetails);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
                }
             }
        });
        //other code that does something

    }

}
```

The button also does some other things but none of it is related to the keyboard and on pressing the button, the activity does not change.

I also have two `EditText` fields in my activity. When I am using the application and i tap on either field, they gain focus and the keyboard appears. When I press the button, the keyboard disappears and the other code is executed exactly as it should be. In this instance, everything is perfect.

The problem arises when tap on either `EditText` field for the second time. Now, the `EditText` gains focus but the keyboard appears and disappears almost instantly without me doing anything. I am guessing my code makes the keyboard disappear permanently after the first time I click the button. Why is this happening and how can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are initializing a `ClickListener` in your `OnClick`. which will hide the keyboard as soon as `heightDiff>100`. Do not do this.

do like this

```
private OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        //other code that does something

    }

}
```

Comment: Doing this solves one problem but creates another! It solves my above mentioned problem. However, even if don't have a focus on my `EditText` and I press the button, the keyboard pops up. When I press the button again, the keyboard gets hidden. This keeps on happening. I am guessing this is because go the toggle functionality. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: oh yes! you only want to hide the keyboard? then try my edit!